# Excel if A1=in between 17 to 20.4 and B1=in between

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, lookup

thanks for reviewing my request, most likely it is simple formula but I'm stuck in research and trying all different formulas so I really need your help. Any help will be appreciated.

```
If A1=in between 17-20.4 and B1=in between 10.5-13.4, so C1=7
If A1=in between 20.5-22.7 and B1=in between 14.5-16.2, so C1=8
If A1=in between 20.5-24.5 and B1=in between 12-15.5, so C1=9
If A1=in between 23.5-28 and B1=in between 14-18.5, so C1=10
```

Both A1 and B1 must match to get value C1, if not 0 or any (error, etc.) All this must be combined formula with for C1 with all values above.

Thank you for all your help.
Have a good day! :)

Comment: Use `AND` function for your criteria within nested `IF` functions.  eg. `=if(and(a1>17,a1<20.4,b1>10.5,b1<13.4),7,if(and(....`

Comment: If A1 is 22, and B1 is 15, what value do you expect for C1 ... 8 or 9?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(A1>17,A1<20.4,B1>10.5,B1<13.4),7,IF(AND(A1>20.5,A1<22.7,B1>14.5,B1<16.2),8,IF(AND(A1>20.5,A1<24.5,B1>12,B1<15.5),9,IF(AND(A1>23.5,A1<28,B1>14,B1<18.5),10,0))))
```